# Toggle function with jQuery maphighlight plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, imagemap

I've just added the jQuery Maphighlight to my app, looking at the docs I'm struggling to get each shape on the imagemap to toggle the highlighted state on click.

I can get one shape to toggle but not multiples

This works for one shape:

```
$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();  

    $('#north').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $('#north').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
      $('#north').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
  });
```

How can I expand on this to cover all the shapes?

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Altering the jQuery selector, like so:

```
 $(function() {

    $('.map').maphilight();  

    // classname optional
    $('.map area.classname').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
      data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
      $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
  });
```